# In Jupyter notebook, how can I manually terminate Keras training using a callback and/or widget event?

Tags: python, keras, jupyter, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

I am using Keras within Jupyter lab to train a model.

I'd like to be able to manually stop training and exit the fitting gracefully.

Right now the only way I can terminate the training is via a KeyboardInterrupt.

How can I use a Keras callback to gracefully terminate - to the extent that my post-Keras code will also execute within the same cell - the training, either by listening to the KeyboardInterrupt or by receiving an event from a widget button?

Or is there another way?

Thanks!

See also [Does interrupting keras training in a Jupyter notebook save the training?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53312642/does-interrupting-keras-training-in-a-jupyter-notebook-save-the-training)

### Edit:

I tried to trap KeyboardInterrupt (i.e. SIGINT sent by the stop button in Jupyter), as follows:

```py
try:
    history=model.fit(...)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

But now I cannot access `history` after the block above (for plotting/persisting etc.). Should I use a callback to write the model on every (few) epoch(s) and load the history from file, or is there another way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this with `self.model.stop_training = True`

Now you need only to find a way to make the `if` became true.

In this example it stop at a defined epoch and batch "hardcoded" (1 and 3), to make it flexible you could read the value of some local txt file for example.

This mean that at the end of every batch or every epoch your callback will read a txt file and if the file start with some sort of defined string the training ends.

```
class My_Callback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs={}):
      self.epoch = epoch

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        if self.epoch == 1 and batch == 3:
          print (f"\nStopping at Epoch {self.epoch}, Batch {batch}")
          self.model.stop_training = True
```

Sorry, but right now i don't have the time to test everything out

Comment: Thank you - I like the idea - so all I would have to do is to populate or even just touch the file and if it's there then act accordingly. I could populate the file manually or with a widget in another notebook if I really wanted to. I wonder if the widget could be in the same cell - will think.

Comment: I updated my question with a potential problem - perhaps you might be able to assist? Thanks!